# How to retrieve current className in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a class:

```
class Dog {

Dog() {
  print("Current classname is: ${this.className}");
}

}
```

It seems this.className is not allowed. Is there something equivalent ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
this.runtimeType
```

or just

```
runtimeType
```

returns the name of the current class.

Comment: This does not work for static methods.  (The use case is for log messages and meta data)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to initialize a variable at the beginning of the class and not in the build method (for instance), the way to go is simply doing as follows:

```
String className = (YourClass).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the attached picture of standalone code that shows an implementation of just getting the class name from this function:

```
void printArea(Shape shape){
  String shapeClass = (shape).runtimeType.toString();
  print('The area of the $shapeClass is: ${shape.area}');
}
```

[Full code on DartPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GN28.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can print the class name using this:

```dart
print('$runtimeType');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the correct asnwer that is up there

```
this.runtimeType
```

is that for if you are dealing with statfull widgets and you want to know the page/widget name you can use the following as well to get the wiget name

```
widget.toString()
```

we do use it for a tracking purpose to track the most pages clicked on etc..

Answer (score 0):

object.runtimeType.toString() or typeObject.toString() (for when the type is inferred from a Generic for example) does not work in release mode for Flutter for Web.

Flutter web runs on dart2js, which will minify your code to reduce the size of your code files. This cannot be turned off in release mode. Since minifying changes class, object and method names, your runtimeType.toString() will become meaningless and unrecognizable.

Ultimately, either avoid taking this path, pass class names as String, or if you absolutely must do this on Flutter web, build in profile mode (as this gives maximum performance with minification turned off).